# Bison / Flex processes tokens in reverse order

Tags: c++, bison, flex-lexer, lex

So I'm trying to understand Bison and Flex (and how the two go together). The example grammar I was given is very simple,

```
e → e plus t
e → t 
t → t TIMES f
t → f
f → LPAREN e RPAREN
f → ID
```

My test input is just "x" and I'm expecting the output to be:

```
"(e (t (f (ID x))))"
```

The actual output I'm getting is:

```
ID x f t
```

I'm wondering why my output is backwards (I haven't added parenthesis yet). Here's my flex and bison files.

Bison:

```
%{
#include "expr-parse-defs.h"
#include <iostream>

    std::string AST;
%}

%union {
  char *sval;
}

%token <sval> ID PLUS TIMES LPAREN RPAREN

%%


e :  
    | e PLUS t          { AST += std::string("e ") + $2 + "t "; }
    | t                 { AST += "t "; }
    ;

t : 
    | t TIMES f         { AST += std::string("t ") + $2 + "f "; }  
    | f                 { AST += "f "; } 
    ;

f : 
    | LPAREN e RPAREN   { AST += $1 + std::string("e ") + $3; }
    | ID                { AST += std::string("ID ") + $1 + " " ; }
    ;

%%


int main() {
    yyparse();
    std::cout << AST;
    return 0;
}
```

Flex:

```
%{
#include <cstring>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include "expr-parse.tab.h"
#include "expr-parse-defs.h"


  using namespace std;
  int tokenpos = 0;

    char * process_token(const char* token){
        // we have to copy because we can't rely on yytext not changing underneath us:
        char *res = new char[strlen(yytext) + 3]; 
        strcpy(res, yytext);
        yylval.sval = res;
    }

%}

ID [a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*

%%
"+"   { yylval.sval = process_token("PLUS"); return PLUS; }
"*"   { yylval.sval = process_token("TIMES"); return TIMES; }
"("   { yylval.sval = process_token("LPAREN"); return LPAREN; }
")"   { yylval.sval = process_token("RPAREN"); return RPAREN; }
{ID}  { yylval.sval = process_token("ID"); return ID; } 
[\n]    

%%

int yyerror(const char *s) {
    cerr << "this is a bad error message and needs to be changed eventually" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I haven't looked at the code in enough detail to be sure, but my immediate reaction is that this is roughly what I'd expect from a bottom-up parser.

Comment: Alright, so it's going to start with the last token it finds?

Comment: No -- it processes tokens in order, but it starts from the bottom of the tree (the most primitive items, such as an ID in your grammar) and works its way up the tree to reach a top-level production. At least as far as I can see, however, you're only looking at the parsing of one token.

Comment: Ok, so if I switched the order to start with e - > t I could get it to print in that order?

Comment: I doubt that would make a difference. Keep in mind that internally it's basically building a tree, and traversing the tree. What matters is primarily the structure of the tree, not the order in which the source code specifies that structure.

Comment: Ok, so I thought about it for a little while and now I want to use the internal value stack to save my strings but now I'm not sure how to pop the stack when Bison has finished looking through the tokens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bison generates a [bottom-up](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bottom-up_parsing) [LALR(1)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LALR) parser. You can imagine its workings like this:

1. It reads one token from the lexer, namely an `ID`.
2. It sees that there is no case where a piece with zero terminals is followed by `ID`, so it knows that it can simply **shift** this token. Now it has that `ID` terminal on its stack.
3. After shifting the token, it reads one more token, which will be the end of input marker in your case.
4. The only valid thing to do with an `ID` is **reducing** it to `f`. So it applies `f → ID` and now has an `f` on its stack.
5. Next it **reduces** using `t → f` to obtain an `t`.
6. As the look-ahead is not `TIMES`, the rule `t → t TIMES f` won't apply, so it **reduces** using `e → t` to obtain `e`.
7. As the look-ahead is not `PLUS` either, there is nothing to shift here either.
8. As `e` is the root symbol, and the look-ahead is the end-of-file marker, you are done.

This bottom-up operation may seem strange to you, but in general is more powerful and can also lead to more descriptive error messages than top-down parsing. You can see at which times it uses the look-ahead to decide the next step. You can also imagine that if you had actual numbers and were implementing some toy calculator, this bottom-up approach would allow you to evaluate parts of the expression before you have parsed the whole expression. The manual has [details on the algorithm](http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Algorithm.html).

> I'm expecting the output to be: `"(e (t (f (ID x))))"`

Then write it this way. As an example, take this:

```
%{
#include "expr-parse-defs.h"
#include <iostream>

#define YYSTYPE std::string;
%}

%token ID PLUS TIMES LPAREN RPAREN

%%

e :  
    | e PLUS t          { $$ = std::string("(e ") + $1 + " " + $3 + ")"; }
    | t                 { $$ = std::string("(e ") + $1 + ")"; }
    ;

[…]
```

This uses strings as the semantic values of your non-terminals. Noite that you [cannot use C++ with non-POD types](http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/C_002b_002b-Semantic-Values.html#C_002b_002b-Semantic-Values) like `std::string`. Now expressions of the form you expected are assembled “inside out” while the parser executes its rules. The approach with the single `AST` variable would work for your simple example, but a rule with two non-terminal children like `e → e plus t` has to combine two strings. Best to use semantic values for this. You can define your own C++ type to hold various information, like e.g. a textual representation of the term, a numeric value, and locations in the source where it was defined.

Comment: I've seen the word textual in several of the Yacc tutorials now, does this just mean a string of some kind (be it char * or std::string)? Also I've been struggling with Bison/Flex for a couple days now and this really helped me.

Comment: @Rawrgulmuffins: Yes, a “[textual](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/textual)” representation is a representation as text, no matter the used data type.